# Facebook Unity SDK 7.15.1 Crashes on FB.Init()

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, apk, facebook-unity-sdk

Using Unity 2017.4.24f1, I created a new project and imported Facebook Unity SDK 7.15.1. Everything runs fine in the editor. After compiling and launching the demo app on my android phone, I clicked the FB.Init() button. The app crashed and exited.

I wish to use Facebook Invite and Share. What should I do?

*** EDIT ***

The problem has been partially solved as I manually downloaded C:\Users\Intel\ .gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10-bin\bg6py687nqv2mbe6e1hdtk57h\gradle-4.10-bin.zip which appears to be a corrupted file at first. After doing a Force Resolve, now I can compile and run the demo app.

However, I am facing another problem as I could not compile my own app. As requested here is the partial error log at the console:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  C:\Users\Intel\Desktop\Quiz Jungle (Master) - 2017.4\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2521: error: expected reference but got (raw string) #000000.
  error: failed linking references.
```

*** EDIT 2 ***

C:\Users\Intel\Desktop\Quiz Jungle (Master) - 2017.4\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2521 looks like this:

```
<style name="Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="statusBarBackground">#000000</item>
</style>
```